Magic link won't work with local supabase
I am using supabase installed locally installed with supabase cli.
Magic links when clicked won't authenticate
I've tried the official documentation, I've tried lots of tutorials
It's happening with Angular projects only (not React as far as I know)
Every time I click on the magic link, I get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
I know my code is working because when I generate a magic link with supabase cloud, everything is working as intended.
I don't know how to make this work locally. Does someone have an idea?
